# Show that the Kernel is equal to the Ideal

Tags: ring-theory

For $ \phi : \mathbb{Z}[\sqrt{-7}] \rightarrow \mathbb{Z}/32$ the function defined by $\phi(a+b\sqrt{-7}) = \overline{a+5b} $ for any $a,b \in \mathbb{Z}$.

How do I show that the kernel of $\phi$ is equal to the ideal $(-5+\sqrt{-7})$ in the ring $\mathbb{Z}[\sqrt{7}]$, and can I apply this method to show that all general kernels of homomorphisms are equal to a certain ideal in a ring?

Comment: I know I have to show one is in the other and vice versa, but I don't know where to start or how to show that.

Comment: What does $\mathbb{Z}/32$ mean here? You mean $Z/Z_{32}$?

Comment: It might help you to answer the following questions: How does an arbitrary element of $(-5 + \sqrt{-7})$ look like? What is its value under $\varphi$? If you take an aribtrary element $x = a + b \sqrt{-7} \in \mathbb{Z}[\sqrt{-7}]$ and assume $\varphi(x) = 0$, then what can you say about $a$ and $b$?

Comment: The ring of integers mod 32. Different institutions may use different notations. $\mathbb{Z}/32$ is {0,1,2,...,31} (all with a bar above but effort to type that out for each one)

Comment: a and b are both 0 or a=-5b @MatthiasKlupsch

Comment: This is not entirely true, for example $x = 7 + 5 \sqrt{-7}$ satisfies $\varphi(x) = 0$. Remember that you have to calculate modulo $32$ in the image.

Answer (score 0):

**Hint:** First check that $I=(-5+\sqrt{-7})\subseteq \ker\phi$ and hence $\phi$ induces homomorphism $\Bbb Z[\sqrt{-7}]/I \to \Bbb Z/32\Bbb Z$. Then prove that the induced homomorphism is isomorphism by finding its inverse.

The general statement that every ideal of a ring is a kernel of a homomorphism is not hard: every ideal $I$ is the kernel of canonical epimorphism $R\to R/I$, and kernel of any homomorphism is indeed ideal in the homomorphisms domain.